# How to footnote two subfigures in one figure

Tags: floats, footnotes, subfloats

I have some trouble with footnotes.

Here is, what i wanted to do:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \subfigure[WSML Varianten\protect\footnotemark]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{wsml-space.pdf}
        \label{subfigure:wsml-space}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Schichten der WSML Varianten\protect\footnotemark]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{wsml-layering.pdf}}
        \caption[WSML Varianten und Schichten]{WSML-Varianten und deren Zusammenspiel im Überblick}
        \label{subfigure:WSML-layer}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{\url{http://www.w3.org/2004/12/rules-ws/paper/44/}~~(aufgerufen am 31.01.2014)}
\footnotetext{\url{http://www.wsmo.org/TR/d16/d16.1/v0.3/20050320/}~~(aufgerufen am 31.01.2014)}
```

Now, the 2 subfigures are marked with "1" and "2", but logically the footenotetext is twice marked with "2".

Any idea to solve this problem?

Greetz
fliflaflex

Comment: Would be great if you could provide a *self-contained* example with *minimal* content. And don't use the obsolete »[subfigure](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)« package but migrate to »[subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig)« and replace `\subfigure` by `\subfloat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for `\footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \subfigure[WSML Varianten\protect\footnotemark]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{wsml-space.pdf}
        \label{subfigure:wsml-space}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Schichten der WSML Varianten\protect\footnotemark]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{wsml-layering.pdf}}
        \caption[WSML Varianten und Schichten]{WSML-Varianten und deren Zusammenspiel im Überblick}
        \label{subfigure:WSML-layer}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext[1]{\url{http://www.w3.org/2004/12/rules-ws/paper/44/}~~(aufgerufen am 31.01.2014)}
\footnotetext{\url{http://www.wsmo.org/TR/d16/d16.1/v0.3/20050320/}~~(aufgerufen am 31.01.2014)}

\end{document}
```

`subfigure` is an obsolete package; you should consider using [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one helped. And i combined it with subfig-package -> \subfloat-command

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend to use `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` and `\stepcounter{footnote}` because the numbering of footnote often changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \subfigure[WSML Varianten\protect\footnotemark]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{wsml-space.pdf}
        \label{subfigure:wsml-space}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Schichten der WSML Varianten\protect\footnotemark]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{wsml-layering.pdf}}
        \caption[WSML Varianten und Schichten]{WSML-Varianten und deren Zusammenspiel im Überblick}
        \label{subfigure:WSML-layer}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{\url{http://www.w3.org/2004/12/rules-ws/paper/44/}~~(aufgerufen am 31.01.2014)}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{\url{http://www.wsmo.org/TR/d16/d16.1/v0.3/20050320/}~~(aufgerufen am 31.01.2014)}

\end{document}
```